# Creation of New Variables

Tags: python

I shared a question last week and I don't think I was able to be very clear.

The code in python is this:

```
RESTRICTIONS = []
RESTRICTIONS.append(1)
RESTRICTIONS.append(2)
RESTRICTIONS.append(3)
RESTRICTIONS.append(4)
RESTRICTIONS.append(5)
for icont in range(3):
     'RESTRICTIONS' + str(icont) = RESTRICTIONS
```

That is, I want each new list to be renamed and receive, initially, the values ​​of the initial list. However, the following error is identified: `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`.

Comment: **Don't do this**. Don't dynamically create variables. Use another container, like a list or a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exec to assign variables using another variable as the name:

```
>>> foo = "bar"
>>> exec(foo + " = 'something else'")
>>> print bar
something else
>>>
```

**But this is poor practice and should be generally avoided.**
What you should use instead is a `dict` to store your values. Something like:

```
restrictions_log = {}
RESTRICTIONS = []
RESTRICTIONS.append(1)
RESTRICTIONS.append(2)
RESTRICTIONS.append(3)
RESTRICTIONS.append(4)
RESTRICTIONS.append(5)
for icont in range(3):
     restrictions_log[str(icont)] = RESTRICTIONS
```

Comment: Be aware that every entry in `restrictions_log` refers to the same list now.

Comment: Note, this will not work in local scopes. You'd have to handle the namespace yourself... in which case you might as well just directly use a `dict`

Comment: Thank you so much, it was almost what I needed.

However, I needed to change the lists later, but I see that when I change, delete or insert values, the same is repeated for the other lists ...

That's right? Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use an assignment operator, you assign the value of what is on the right to the variable or element on the left. Example:

A = B + C
Assigment operator = must always be the first operator from right to left. So in every programming language, this is impossible:

B + C = A

possible: A = 3*3+8
impossible: 3*3+8 = A

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Anyway. Looking at your previous question, is this what you are looking for ?

```
restrictions = []
restrictions.extend(range(1,6))
for i in range(3):
    print(f'restrictions.{i+1} = {restrictions[i]}')
```

If you like to do it with concatenation:

```
restrictions = []
restrictions.extend(range(1,6))
for i in range(3):
    print('restrictions.' + str(i+1) + ' = ' + str(restrictions[i]))
```

Hope it helps.